# set methodcalls for service at runtime in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to set a method call on a service in Symfony2 at runtime?

I would like to set something like this at runtime:

```
calls:
            - [ setEventDispatcher, [ @event_dispatcher ] ]
```

The scenario would be:
There is a listener on an onKernel event that would check if a parameter is set in the request and then add the method call to the service in the container.
So the lazy loading would be kept, i guess.

I saw there is a method *setMethodCalls()* in the builder, so maybe i could use this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question... Why don't you simply use it as it is described? Each time you initialize your service, it will call method from `calls` block.

Comment: Because i want the methods only to be called when a certain condition is on. And i want the DIC to do it to keep lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your bundle you should extend from `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader` and rewrite there method [`parseDefinition()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php#L194) to fetch not only `calls` section, but also your custom section with some conditions you want to use.

And in the end, you'll have service configuration something like this:

```
calls:
    always:
        - [ setEventDispatcher, [ @event_dispatcher ] ]
    on_condition:
        variable: "value"
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: yeah thats a good idea +1. but i am actually lookin for a modification on runtime.